# Openlayer Projection

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers, proj4js

I want to zoom to a particular house in the google mapS, but when I provide its bounds and lattitude and longitude,  it does not show images as well as the particular house. Can anyone provide the solution for this?

Comment: Could you show us your code? It's much easier to help that way.

Comment: Yes the question has very little to go on - the problem could be in your code, your data provider, etc. You mention projection in the title: If you think this is the problem, look at the Proj4js docs to make sure your projection parameters are correct (OpenLayers uses Proj4js for reproductions)

Answer (score 0):

Solution would be probably to transporm coordinates first. Unfortunately when You pass coordinates to OpanLayers.LonLat(lon,lat) it is supposed to be WGS:84, while OpenLayer.Bounds() needs coordinates given in EPSG:900913.
You should then use Proj4js.transform and pass transformed coordintes in EPSG:900913

Comment: Do yo know more exhausting explanation of this somewhere in web?

Answer (score 0):

You can transform it like this one:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
var location.transform(map.getProjectionObject(), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
```